# Create callout from label to edge of polygon with Geometry generator with QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry, geometry-generator

With `make_line(centroid ($geometry), make_point("x","y"))` you can draw a line between the label and the center of an polygon, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to draw a line just between the border/edge of the polygon and the label?

The polygons have a transparent fill, so cannot just be drawn over the line.

---

Yes, the polygons are separate from each other or located at the edges. Is there any possibility to change the ankerpoint from endpoint of the polygon to the nearest point between the edge/border of the polygon and the label?

So that i can adjust the Label all around the polygon with a connection line between label and polygon edge/border?

Comment: Are the circles connected or separate from each other?

Comment: Maybe with `closest_point` ? ... but i think u got to have an attribute in common linking the object and the label ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the polygons are separate from each other or located at the edges, then you can use the following expression in the Geometry Generator:

```
difference(make_line(end_point($geometry),make_point("Label_x","Label_y"),$geometry), buffer(make_point("Label_x","Label_y"),0.001))
```

and it will give the following result:

[image]

But, it will not work if the polygons are located in the center among other polygons as in the following example:

[image]